# Imageview with rounded image not working

Tags: android, image

In my app i want the image round.I am using the following method to round the image.

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {


Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

And i am using following xml:

```
<ImageView 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/default_profilepic"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

And i am using the imageloader class,because i am getting image url.So in my class i used follwing code:

```
imgLoader.DisplayImage(strFBProfilePic, imgProfilePic);
```

And in my imageloader class i used bellow code in displayimage method:

```
dispImage=ImageHelper.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, 150);
imageView.setImageBitmap(dispImage);
```

And finally i got the output like the following:

[image]

So please suggest what i did mistaken in my code.Tanks In advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the second parameter of `getRoundedCornerBitmap` method is the radius of the corners. Try giving a smaller value, such as

```
dispImage = ImageHelper.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, 10);
```

Comment: it is not working,if i use 10 i got rectanglar image.but i want rounded image

Comment: Well, maybe 10 is not enough. Just try and adjust the parameter, until you get the result you expect.

Comment: yes i tried 50,100,150 and 200 also.but i got same output only

Comment: Mmh weird, what're the dimensions of the original image?

Comment: This Width:180,Hight:135 of original image

Comment: Not sure if scaleType may have something to do. Try removing `scaleType` property, and set width and height to `wrap_content`